# The problem: found a tab character that violate intendation

Tags: perl, yaml, indentation, cpan

```
./run-bot
Running bot 22496
Error parsing ./shittybot.yml: YAML::XS::Load Error: The problem:

    found a tab character that violate intendation

was found at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/Any.pm line 201
        Config::Any::_load('Config::Any', 'HASH(0x8de4708)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/Any.pm line 94
        Config::Any::load_files('Config::Any', 'HASH(0x8de4708)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI/Source/Loader.pm line 104
        Config::JFDI::Source::Loader::_load_files('Config::JFDI::Source::Loader=HASH(0x85e1d48)', 'ARRAY(0x8de4f48)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI/Source/Loader.pm line 62
        Config::JFDI::Source::Loader::read('Config::JFDI::Source::Loader=HASH(0x85e1d48)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI.pm line 153
        Config::JFDI::load('Config::JFDI=HASH(0x85e67c0)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI.pm line 140
        Config::JFDI::config('Config::JFDI=HASH(0x85e67c0)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI.pm line 131
        Config::JFDI::get('Config::JFDI=HASH(0x85e67c0)') called at bot.pl line 32
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT:  I fixed indentation I think, but now I get this error:

```
Error parsing ./shittybot.yml: YAML::XS::Load Error: The problem:

    found character that cannot start any token

was found at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/Any.pm line 201
        Config::Any::_load('Config::Any', 'HASH(0xa3da738)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/Any.pm line 94
        Config::Any::load_files('Config::Any', 'HASH(0xa3da738)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI/Source/Loader.pm line 104
        Config::JFDI::Source::Loader::_load_files('Config::JFDI::Source::Loader=HASH(0x9bd7d48)', 'ARRAY(0xa3daf78)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI/Source/Loader.pm line 62
        Config::JFDI::Source::Loader::read('Config::JFDI::Source::Loader=HASH(0x9bd7d48)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI.pm line 153
        Config::JFDI::load('Config::JFDI=HASH(0x9bdc7c0)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI.pm line 140
        Config::JFDI::config('Config::JFDI=HASH(0x9bdc7c0)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/Config/JFDI.pm line 131
        Config::JFDI::get('Config::JFDI=HASH(0x9bdc7c0)') called at bot.pl line 32
```

Comment: can you upload `shittybot.yml` somewhere? Also, couldn't you have picked a more tasteful name for a public forum?

Comment: please ask a new question if you have a new problem; don't remove the old one by editing it. The whole point of this website is future users can see the answer to the original question.

Comment: Edited to restore the text of the original question prior to showing the new error.  OP, as Philip Potter said, please do not delete the text of your questions after they are resolved, as that prevents future users from finding them if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. Replace all spaces with tabs
2. Ensure everything is properly indented.

Answer (score 3):

With your pastebin file.

```
apv@cassidy[421]~/>perl -MYAML::XS=LoadFile -le 'LoadFile(+shift)' S1tuACcg.txt
             YAML::XS::Load Error: The problem:

    found a tab character that violate intendation

was found at document: 1, line: 8, column: 1
while scanning a plain scalar at line: 7, column: 18    
apv@cassidy[422]~/>perl -lne 'print "TAB!" if /\t/' S1tuACcg.txt
TAB!
TAB!
TAB!
apv@cassidy[423]~/>perl -pi -e 's/\t/        /' S1tuACcg.txt
apv@cassidy[424]~/>perl -MYAML::XS=LoadFile -le \
   'LoadFile(+shift) and print "OK!"' S1tuACcg.txt
OK!
```

I suspect that if you upgrade your YAML::XS (mine’s 0.34), you’ll see the better error feedback my example shows.